# How to adjust wordpress shortcode that contains javascript, to jquery ajax (without plugin creation)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, shortcode

Last couple of days I've been reading about usage of ajax in wordpress context, and all that I came across were long examples including plugin creation process... that I can't seem to adjust to my own purpose - that purpose being the creation of shortcode for usage in the default wordpress text widget, more than one time.

My shortcode (in functions.php) is this:

```
function video_playlist_shortcode($atts) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts(
  array(
  'link' => '',
  'thumbnail' => '',
  'description' => ''
  ), $atts, 'playlist');

  return '<div class="video-item" onClick="document.querySelector("#video-frame").src="'.$atts['link'].'?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1"">
  <div class="video-thumbnail">
    <img src="'.$atts['thumbnail'].'" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="description">'.$atts['description'].'</div>
  </div>';
}
add_shortcode('playlist', 'video_playlist_shortcode');
```

And it prints the content of the shortcode as I want it, but the javascript code part in the shortcode doesn't work obviously. But I have no idea how to extract it and use it with ajax.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your line here

```
return '<div class="video-item" onClick="document.querySelector("#video-frame").src="'.$atts['link'].'?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1"">
```

You have a problem where you're including three nested quotes and not closing things properly.

1. The first single quote enclosing the whole string
2. The double quote for the onClick
3. The double quote for the querySelector()

You need to escape the 3rd ( querySelector() )quotes like this: \'#video-frame\'
So that they function, then close the 2nd ( onClick ) quotes properly. It looks like you were trying to concatenate the src afterwards (looking at that period) but then you have two closing double quotes at the end there and no space between the onClick and src.

Try this:

```
 return '<div class="video-item" onClick="document.querySelector(\'#video-frame\')" ' . 'src="'.$atts['link'].'?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1">
```

Edit: I incorrectly put escaped double quotes, escaped single quotes should do the trick

Comment: You are right about mixup of double quotes... yet your solution breaks my code, because the dot after the jquery selector is a part of the same javascript code, it doesn't go in between the quotes like it's part of php code. And when I resolve that, javascript still doesn't work in the shortcode, because it's on the server side. That's why I need ajax.

Comment: Ah I see now, you're right. Can you update your original post with an edit at the bottom with the new code including your ajax?

Comment: If I had any idea how to do that with ajax, I would... anyway, this was a part of my javascript based youtube video player. But I found a suitable plugin option after few days (most of plugins were awful). Thank you for your effort.